# jQuery 'OR' statement (' | | ') is not working in if condition

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown with several options. I need to colorize those options as follows.

if Option value == "f1" **OR** Option value =="f2" then dropdown color = "blue"

else dropdown color = "red"

This is the code:

```
<select id="selector">
    <option value>Default</option>
    <option value="f1">Fruit 1</option>
    <option value="f2">Fruit 2</option>
    <option value="v1">Vege 1</option>
    <option value="v2">Vege 2</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#selector').on('change', function()
    {
        var selected_v = this.value;

        $(this).find("option").css("color", "blue");
        $(this).css("color", "blue");

        if ((selected_v != "f1") || (selected_v != "f2")) {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is working for `if ( (selected_v != "f1") )` but with second condition followed by `||` it doesn't work. With **OR** operator and second condition, all the options will be red. What is the wrong here?

**Live code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/s7ry1cvp/

Comment: Why didn't you do it the way you described then?

Comment: Use `&&` AND operator because you want `selected_v` not equal to "f1" AND not equal to "f2".

Comment: When `selected_v` is equal to "f1" it is NOT equal to "f2". So read your logic. If "selected_v is not equal to f1 OR selected_v is not equal to f2" So your code is basically saying that  the variable needs to be two values for it to be true, problem is, a variable can only be one thing.

Comment: This reads like a logic problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: Beyond that ... setting color of the  `<select>` will not be seen since you are setting color of each `<option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `if` statement. You are comparing the variable where it is NOT equal to a certain value, OR comparing again where it is NOT equal to a different value. Because of the OR it will always execute the code inside the `if` block. What is required is `selected_v` NOT equal to `"f1"` AND `selected_v` NOT equal to `"f2"`.

Try using `&&` operator:

```
if ( (selected_v != "f1") && (selected_v != "f2") ) {
    $(this).css("color", "red");
 }
```

Or you could code it as you stated:

```
if ( (selected_v == "f1") || (selected_v == "f2") ) {
   $(this).css("color", "blue");
}
else
{
    $(this).css("color", "red");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's always gonna equate to true. Think about it. If it's value is `f2` then it isn't `f1`, if it's value is `v1` then it isn't `f1` **and** it isn't `f2`.

As I've highlighted, you need to use the `and` operator (`&&`) instead of `or` (`||`)

Comment: Maybe - have amended to say to use the and operator @treyBake